# Passing & in query string

Tags: php

I want to pass '&' operator in query string. I tried to use urlencode and urldecode 
but its not working. I am doing this:

```
$abc="A & B";
$abc2=urlencode($abc);
```

Then I am passing the value like this

```
<a href="hello.php?say=<?php echo $abc2 ?>"><?php echo $abc;?></a>
```

and getting value on next page as

```
$abc=$_GET['say'];
$abcd=urldecode($abc');
echo $abcd;
```

but the output is not `A & B`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try echo `$_GET['say']` **without** `urldecode()`? You can always use `http_buil_query()`, which would be a nice, clean approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it should work I tried the following on my webserver:

```
$a = 'A & B';
echo urlencode($a);
echo '<br />';
echo urldecode(urlencode($a));
```

Output

```
A+%26+B
A & B
```

I guess you have another logically or syntax error which causes your & not to be decoded correctly, in your code there's an apostroph in your urldecode()-syntax.

Is that all of your code or are you using a "similiar" one? your original code would be useful then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$url = '?' . http_build_query(array(
  'say' => 'A & B'
));

// Then just:
echo $_GET['say'];
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ibH79a?say=A+%26+B

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have added a single quote next to $abc on line 2 in the below code:

```
$abc = $_GET['say'];
$abcd = urldecode($abc);
echo $abcd;
```

Answer (score -1):

& is a special HTML characters, you need to convert it to `&amp;`.

Try this:

```
$abc = "A & B";
<a href="hello.php?say=<?php echo htmlentities($abc); ?>"><?php echo $abc; ?></a>
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space. `&amp;` is an ampersand encoded as an HTML entity. In this case, however, `urlencode()` should be used, not `htmlentities()`.

Comment: ah, sorry. @RikkusRukkus is correct. What i mean is &amp; :-)

Comment: You're right again. & is converted to %NN by urlencode(), so no need to use htmlentities(). But, it *should* be used in <?php echo $abc; ?> (become: <?php echo htmlentities($abc); ?>, because & will generate warning by HTML validator. It should be &amp;