# PHP - $_GET Parameter with a "&" in it

Tags: php, get, special-characters

I tried to give an string like "A&B" as a parameter to a php file.
But because '&' Symbols are used to give multiple params to the file this doesn't work:

```
http://localhost/Projekte/programm.php?division=A&B
```

How can I pass this string?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222763/6105873), using url_encode() and url_decode()

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem. I'm german and didn't know that there was an acual word for '&', so i didn't find it at my research. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/Projekte/programm.php?division=' . urlencode('A&B');
echo $url;
```

*Output*

```
http://localhost/Projekte/programm.php?division=A%26B
```

*Accessing the GET parameter from programm.php*

```
var_dump($_GET['division']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `url_encode()` function and `url_decode()` functions. These will replace all alphanumeric characters with the appropriate %.. value

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost/Projekte/programm.php?division1=a&division2=b


echo $_GET["division1"];
echo $_GET["division2"];
```

& is multiple value but it must be name and value
so give name1=value&name2=value

or

```
http://localhost/Projekte/programm.php?division=A&b


$val1 = $_GET["division"];

$val2 = explode("&", $val1);

echo $val2[0].$val[1];
```