# Ampersand doesn't load in Query String - PHP

Tags: php, ampersand

I'm passing simple query string:

```
index.php?a=orange&apple
```

Getting value with:

```
$_GET['a'];
```

it only shows `orange` value. i have tried

```
$a = urlencode($_GET['a']);
$rs = urldecode($a);
echo $rs; // orange;
```

but didn't work. Found similar question here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222685/passing-in-query-string) but seems not useful. How do i get complete value `orange&apple`?

Comment: Other than encoding the ampersand?

Comment: URL Should be : `index.php?a=orange%26apple`

Comment: it shows just first value which comes before `&` like `orange` without encoding.

Comment: this might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `&` makes `apple` as another value in `GET` request.

Like this -

```
/test/demo_form.php?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

So use `'%26'`(encoding URI Component) in place of `&` like this -

```
index.php?a=orange%26apple
```

And get the value with `$_GET['a'];`. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your query string need to encode ampersand(&) as percent-encode as %26. Your url will be like :

```
index.php?a=orange%26apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
index.php?a=orange&b=apple

// Values

$_GET['a'];
$_GET['b'];
```